# Bluetooth is not working in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, bluetooth

I am using Sony Vaio laptop and I have installed 12.04. My bluetooth is not working. Neither it can search any device nor the opposite. I generally use bluetooth modem
(mobile phone) for Internet in home but unable to do this.

Please help me to solve the problem. I have seen many posts regarding this problem and tried all possible solutions but those could not solve the problem.

Comment: Is there a hardware switch for Bluetooth?

Answer (score 1):

Please post the output of `rfkill list`

- If bluetooth is soft blocked, try `sudo rfkill unblock bluetooth`
- If it's hard blocked, you have to search for a hardware switch or bios setting

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, But then figured it out that the **network adapter was switched off with the explicit function key provided by the laptop manufacturer when I was using windows.** The blue tooth in Ubuntu started working after it was enabled in the windows boot