# Bluetooth seems to be feeling blue. How do I make it work?

Tags: 12.04, bluetooth

I looked at the solutions here :

- [Trouble turning on bluetooth in 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/153384/trouble-turning-on-bluetooth-in-12-04)
- [Bluetooth is not working in Ubuntu 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/182869/bluetooth-is-not-working-in-ubuntu-12-04?rq=1)
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/180678/bluetooth-isnt-working-in-12-04?rq=1
- [Dell Laptop's Bluetooth isn't detected by Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/184475/dell-laptops-bluetooth-isnt-detected-by-ubuntu?rq=1) : Not entirely clear what exactly is being suggested on this one
- [bluetooth not working after installing Ubuntu 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/227663/bluetooth-not-working-after-installing-ubuntu-12-04?rq=1)
- [I can't turn on my bluetooth?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/247861/i-cant-turn-on-my-bluetooth?rq=1)

---

None of those work for me. I have a Asus U32U laptop with 12.04 installed. Bluetooth has never worked correctly for me in the past. Previously, I used to stop and start the bluetooth service manually and that used to do the trick. However, that solution stopped working since the latest set of updates.

What can I do to make it work correctly or at the very least, make it work at all?

---

```
U32U:~$ rfkill list
...
2: asus-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

U32U:~$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 058f:a014 Alcor Micro Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 12d1:140b Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. EC1260 Wireless Data Modem HSD USB Card
Bus 004 Device 003: ID 0cf3:3005 Atheros Communications, Inc. AR3011 Bluetooth
```

Answer (score 3):

Try installing blueman bluetooth manager from the software center. It worked for me.

Comment: Unfortunately I think this might actually be the solution. The default bluetooth manager doesn't work very well. Installing blueman solved my problems as well. (cc @AsheeshR)

Comment: Doesnt help!...